Locks on catalog tables
I have created a procedure that returns an event trigger:
Whenever an ALTER TABLE occurs SELECT is granted on all sequences on all tables to a specific user.
During restore of the db the above fails in some occasions with a tuple concurrently updated error:
[2024-04-25T15:55:23.586Z] pg_restore: error: pg_restore:could not execute query: ERROR:  tuple concurrently updated
[2024-04-25T15:55:23.586Z] CONTEXT:  SQL statement "GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO ..."
[2024-04-25T15:55:23.586Z] PL/pgSQL function xxx.fake_sth() line 13 at SQL statement
[2024-04-25T15:55:23.586Z] Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.table_name
[2024-04-25T15:55:23.586Z]     ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (id);
[2024-04-25T15:55:23.586Z] 
[2024-04-25T15:55:23.586Z] 

I read that there is no lock mechanism regarding catalog tables. So I assume that ALTER triggers the execution of the function and the grant fails because a lock is held by the ALTER on the pg_class table and the grant fails as it needs to acquire a lock on pg_class table.
Is there a way to overcome this?
I thought of acquiring a lock immediately before the GRANT statement but on rds permission is denied. Is there another way of achieving this?
The function code is:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shared_extensions.foo_grant_r_seq_function()
 RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE

    obj record;

BEGIN

FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()

LOOP

-- ALTER TABLE has been added because a sequence can be also created
-- with ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY.
IF obj.command_tag IN ('CREATE SEQUENCE', 'CREATE TABLE', 'ALTER TABLE') THEN
    GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO foo;
END IF;

END LOOP;

END;
$function$;


You are trying to update the same row twice. Please show us the trigger function.

@LaurenzAlbe added in description

I cannot pinpoint the exact failure. But why don't you solve the problem in a better way by using ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES to change the default privileges of sequences?

Yes @LaurenzAlbe this is what i did already! Thanks!
